# How can I use CDATA with generated C# classes from xsd.exe?

Tags: c#, xml, cdata, xsd.exe

**Problem**

I'm trying to fill in a section at the moment that maps to an `xs:string` and write this to XML.

I've put the generated code of this  value at the bottom of this post as it's a bit long.

Previously I just assigned it the string value.

```
rawdata.data = generatedString;
```

But when I tried this.

```
rawdata.data = "<![CDATA[" + generatedString + "]]>";
```

The eventual output formats the CDATA part anyway.

```
&lt;![CDATA[
```

Is there any way that I can avoid this happening so that CDATA appears as it's meant to?

**Extra Information**

Generated code for this field.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class DataFilesRawdata
{

    private string idField;

    private string dataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @SeM is what I think is the most correct solution according to how Microsoft built the XML serializer but as I need to regenerate the classes from XSD *relatively* often I decided it was better to try to find another solution instead of manually editing the generated classes after every time they're built.

In this vein I found that instead of modifying the generated classes, I could override the XmlSerializer so that if it came across CDATA content it would be able to handle it.

Of course this only works if the CDATA is at the very start and very end of the element. It suits my use case in that regard but does not universally achieve all use cases.

```
using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(tempFilePath,FileMode.Create))
{                
    var xmlwriter = new CustomXmlTextWriter(fileStream);
    xmls.Serialize(xmlwriter, contents, ns);
}
```

And the custom writer.

```
public class CustomXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{

    //... constructor if you need it

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (text.StartsWith("<![CDATA[") && text.EndsWith("]]>"))
        {
            base.WriteRaw(text);
            return;
        }
        base.WriteString(text);
    }

}
```

It looks like this is along the lines of which Microsoft took.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#SMDiagnostics/System/ServiceModel/Diagnostics/PlainXmlWriter.cs,137

Comment: Nice solution, really.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[XmlCDataSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlcdatasection?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Xml.XmlCDataSection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2)** for that:

```
[XmlElement("data")]
public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection Data { get; set; }
```

it will automatically create CData sections in your xml, if you serialize your object.

Assign it:

```
rawdata.data = System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(generatedString);
```

Comment: I think that would work although it would require modifying the auto-generated classes. I wonder if I can leverage the fact that most of the generated classes are `partial` classes to maintain my changes throughout following regenerations.

Comment: its auto-generated by what?

Comment: The XML Schema Defintion Tool `xsd.exe` tool in the Microsoft SDK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe